# Easyphp 16.1.1 How do I switch to PHP 7 form PHP 5.6

Tags: php, easyphp

I just installed Easyphp 16.1.1. It defaults to PHP version 5.6.19. I would like to you PHP 7. They are both listed as options, but I haven't been able to find a way to switch versions. Is there a way to change versions?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily go to the Dashboard

http://localhost:1111

'Applications' > 'HTTP Server' > 'Apache' > press 'STOP' (if it's started) > choose the 'PHP version' value > press 'start' , enjoy !

Comment: With a side note that EasyPHP tend not to package the latest version of PHP, and try to sell you a 10$/year subscription that allows you to update to the actual lastest version. If you need the lasted version, and not just an older version of PHP7, then check the other answer below from IndyGeorgios and don't forget to put the config file in read only.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the PHP7 folder inside `EasyPphp\eds-binaries\php\` and can't start the server after you've selected the php7 from the list you probably dont't have the right Visual C++ Redistributable.

For PHP7 you need **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable**; you can find it here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145
(install both x64 and x86 versions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know if that would have fixed my issue or not. I believe software should be user friendly and the new version of EasyPhp is not. I dumped it and switched to Wamp.

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to \eds-binaries\httpserver\apachexxxx*\conf\, find httpd-php.conf, keep a backup for safety and then edit it and change the php5xxx paths to the php7xxx ones --check the proper folders to see what they are called.

* (whatever version of apache you have, navigate through windows to be sure)

Comment: I forgot to say that you should change any other reference to php5 in this file to php7. Also, when the http server restarts, it reverts to the original, I managed to make it work by making the file read-only, but there probably is a better way, another settings file for eds itself most probably, I don't know.

Comment: This is not exact solution. The exact solution is given below because after following this on restart server httpd-php.conf get reset.

Comment: This is the right answer, provided that you put the httpd-php.cong file in read only. It would be better if there was a way to unpack PHP into the eds-binairies/php folder and somehow had it listed in the easyphp drop down, but I have yet to figure out the last part.

Answer (score 1):

In Dashboard under applications, you add the version of PHP you need.
Then choose HTTP Server and your version of Apache, in the dropdown for PHP version choose the version of PHP you just added.